# How can I search for Flickr photos using one parameter (like the name) and get its url using python?

Tags: python, search, flickr

I have the Flickr api key. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that fetches ids of photos for url

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lxml import etree
import urllib

f=urllib.urlopen('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&text=sometextyousearch&extras=url_sq')

doc = etree.XML(f.read())

print [ photo.get('id') for photo in doc.iterfind(".//photo") ]
```

What you have to do, is to define your path to flickr api

I don't have api key so I can't test it but if you look [here](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) you see according the documentation that you address will look similar to url I posted in my code, you will have to attach your api key of course

And you'll choose one of the `url_sq, url_t, url_s, url_m, url_z, url_l, url_o`
that suits you, and in the code change `photo.get('id')` to url you choose

Good luck

// sorry I couldn't paste here complete example, but I don't want to obtain flickr api key just for nothing, if you have any problems feel free to ask

Comment: Is this the correct url to choose? http://farm6.static.flickr.com/"+ph['server']+"/"+ph['id']+"_"+ph['secret']+".jpg"

Comment: if you mean the url, from which you'll download your data, it should be url similar to that in my post `api.flickr.com/services/rest/?....`

Comment: It'll be much easier when you use a Python library to interface with Flickr, such as http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi